# How are potion effects determined?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What I mean by my question is: how does Skyrim determine whether something is a potion or poison....or even what that Poison/Potion is based off?

Like say we have 2 ingredients that both have Fortify Strength and both have Damage Stamina for instance....How do we know what it's going to end up as?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of the effects will be present in the potion, but the order of the effects in the ingredient list determines which will be stronger and will appear as the label.  The effect that is higher in the list will be the dominant effect and serve as the label, if you have both potion and poison effects on your two ingredients.  By "higher"  I mean as you look at the screen, the effect closer to the top of the screen.

Comment: yup, that's exactly how it works,   For example, the 2 item poison potion of bear claws + hanging moss is always a poison since damage magicka regen is always the first effect listed.

Comment: I thought it was maybe based on the effect "value"

Comment: It is based on the effect value. The properties of a mixture are figured before perks like benefactor or poisoner, based on the most expensive effect. Damage Magicka Regen is the most expensive effect for Bear Claw and Hanging Moss(second only to Paralysis at  a base of 265 versus 285) so it makes a poison. Between Fortify Carry weight and Damage Stamina, Carry weight is more valuable(base value over 200) so it will be a potion(Even Damage Stamina Regen is base value 159, and plain damage stamina is about half that or less).